# Playing Audio while in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, background, activity-lifecycle

I've attempted to implement suggestions regarding playing audio while in background mode, but nothing is working. My info.plist looks like this:

[image]

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

In `viewDidLoad`, I have this code:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

I believe that these are the requirements to allow the audio to continue playing. However, as soon as I hit 'home' or the lock button, the audio stops playing.

I put some logging into my app delegate, and I can see that as soon as I hit the home button, my app goes directly into the `applicationWillTerminate` (skipping `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

There must be something wrong with my setup, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to xcode and select target of the project then go to the Capabilities tab and in then change the status of Background Mode 'OFF' to 'ON'. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the issue. In my case, the flag that you mention was already set to ON.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. There was also a setting in info.plist called

`Application does not run in background`

This was set to `YES`, which I assume is the default, since I don't think that I ever changed this. Obviously, it needs to be set to `NO`.